# mqtt broker 1.4.1 with auth plugin, backend mysql, failed to sub/pub, wrong user name or pwd

Tags: mysql, authentication, plugins, mqtt, mosquitto

i am working on mqtt broker 1.4.1 with authentication plugin, backend is mysql.

```
 /etc/mosquitto $ sudo /usr/local/sbin/mosquitto -c mosquitto.conf
```

> 1435208131: mosquitto version 1.4.1 (build date 2015-05-07 17:19:21+0800) starting
>
> 1435208131: Config loaded from mosquitto.conf.
>
> 1435208131: |-- *** auth-plug: startup
>
> 1435208131: |-- ** Configured order: mysql
>
> 1435208131: |-- }}}} MYSQL
>
> 1435208131: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
>
> 1435208131: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
>
> 1435208131: Warning: Address family not supported by protocol
>
> 1435208142: New connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 1883.
>
> 1435208142: |-- mosquitto_auth_unpwd_check(Leo)
>
> 1435208142: |-- ** checking backend mysql
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '▒▒Leo’' at line 1
>
> 1435208142: |-- getuser(Leo) AUTHENTICATED=0 by none
>
> 1435208142: Sending CONNACK to 127.0.0.1 (0, 4)
>
> 1435208142: Socket error on client , disconnecting.

in mysql, i use `INSERT INTO users (username, pw) VALUES ('Leo', 'PBKDF2$sha256$901$...$...');`
and `INSERT INTO acls (username, topic, rw) VALUES ('Leo', 'Leo/#', 2);`
commands to create test user and its topic control.

when i run `sudo mosquitto_sub -h localhost -p 1883 -u Leo -P Leo -t Leo/#` i always get below error:

> Connection Refused: bad user name or password.

any hints of this error? thanks,Leo

----here is Mosquitto configuration file

```
sudo nano /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf
```

> autosave_interval 1800
>
> persistence true
>
> persistence_file m2.db
>
> persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/
>
> connection_messages true
>
> log_timestamp true
>
> log_dest stderr
>
> log_type error
>
> log_type warning
>
> log_type debug
>
> log_type notice
>
> log_type information
>
> log_type all
>
> auth_plugin /etc/mosquitto/auth-plug.so
>
> auth_opt_backends mysql
>
> auth_opt_host localhost
>
> auth_opt_port 3306
>
> auth_opt_dbname sql_iocaremqtt
>
> auth_opt_user pi
>
> auth_opt_pass rpi
>
> auth_opt_userquery SELECT pw FROM users WHERE username = ‘%s’
>
> auth_opt_superquery SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username = ‘%s’ AND super = 1
>
> auth_opt_aclquery SELECT topic FROM acls WHERE (username = '%s') AND (rw >= %d)
>
> port 1883
>
> protocol mqtt

and here is user and table in mysql:

```
mysql> select * from users;
```

> +----+----------+----------------------------------------------------+-------+
>
> | id | username | pw                                                 | super |
>
> +----+----------+----------------------------------------------------+-------+
>
> |  1   | Leo      | PBKDF2$sha256$901$...$...                        |     0 |
>
> +----+----------+----------------------------------------------------+-------+

```
mysql> select * from acls;
```

> +----+----------+----------------+----+
>
> | id | username | topic     | rw |
>
> +----+----------+----------------+----+
>
> |  1  | Leo      | Leo/#          |  2 |
>
> +----+----------+----------------+----+

Comment: I would think it is your connection string not the insert statement.

Comment: Update the question with the section of your config file that has your database connection parameters so we can help work out what's wrong

Comment: ok, updated. thanks for your kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the single quotes around your %s. Some of them are "fancy", like ‘%s’ and some of them are plain (as they should be) like '%s'. The difference is very obvious in the stackoverflow editor. Make them all plain single quotes `'`.